# Run-time error '3020' only on home computer (MS Access VBA, Office 2016)

Tags: ms-access, vba

Came home to continue working on a project.  Suddenly I have a Run-time error '3020': "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit" landing on this line `Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!ChangedAsOf.Value = Now.`   Called into work to ask if they are getting the error.  No, it runs perfectly.  I asked her to furnish me another copy, but I get the same thing.  We both have MS Access 2016, except mine is Office 365.

Short description of how it is supposed to work:

1. User clicks in a Subform sf_COB_DISTR on a parent form frm_COB from a field called "Latest AFP"
2. They are taken to another form called DISTRO to a checkbook-like register, ready to enter an adjustment.

This is the routine that runs when user clicks in "LATEST AFP"

```
Private Sub LATEST_AFP_Click()
      OccupyDistr ("ANNUAL")
End Sub
```

Definition:

```
Sub OccupyDistr(strANNUALorALLOCATION As String)

        Form_frm_COB.lblDistroType.Caption = "ADJ" 'This is to make sure to ask to send an email

        Dim bBeingEdited As Boolean
        Dim strOccupiedDetails As String
        Dim strOccupiedBy As String
        Dim strReason As String

        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_DISTR WHERE DISTR_ID=" & Me.DISTR_ID, dbOpenDynaset)

        bBeingEdited = DLookup("BeingEdited", "tbl_DISTR", "DISTR_ID=" & Me.DISTR_ID)
        strOccupiedBy = Nz(DLookup("OccupiedBy", "tbl_DISTR", "DISTR_ID=" & Me.DISTR_ID), "VACANT")
        strOccupiedDetails = Nz(DLookup("OccupiedDetail", "tbl_DISTR", "DISTR_ID=" & Me.DISTR_ID), "VACANT")

        strReason = Now() & " For " & strANNUALorALLOCATION

        If bBeingEdited = False Then
            rs.Edit
            rs!BeingEdited = -1
            rs!OccupiedBy = AcquireUser
            rs!OccupiedDetail = strReason
            rs.Update

            Set rs = Nothing

            Select Case strANNUALorALLOCATION

            Case "LOA"
                EditLOA
            Case "ANNUAL"
                EditANNUAL
            Case "ALLOCATION"
                EditALLOCATION
            End Select

        Else
            MsgBox strOccupiedBy & " has been in this record since " & strOccupiedDetails, vbInformation, "Record being edited"
        End If


        End Sub
```

This is the subroutine that produces the error:

```
 Public Sub AdjustDistro(ByVal strAFP_Allo As String, ByVal cLatest As Currency, ByVal strDISTRO_NUM As String)
 Dim strSQL As String


   Select Case strAFP_Allo

   Case "AFP"


        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Visible = True

        Form_DISTRO.txtTOT_WAFP.Requery
        Form_DISTRO.txtRemainingCalc.Requery

        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(0).Visible = True
        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(0).SetFocus
        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(1).Visible = False
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.SetFocus


        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form.AllowAdditions = True
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form.AllowEdits = True
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form.AllowDeletions = True

        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!ChangedBy.Value = AcquireUser
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!ChangedAsOf.Value = Now
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!COB_ID = Form_DISTRO.COB_ID 
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!txtAFP.Value = cLatest
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!txtADJ_DATE = Date
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!txtDISTRO_NUM = strDISTRO_NUM
        Form_DISTRO.sfAFP.Form!txtADJUSTMENT.SetFocus

    Case "ALLO"

        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Visible = True
        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(1).Visible = True
        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(1).SetFocus
        Form_DISTRO.tbMain.Pages(0).Visible = False
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.SetFocus

        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form.AllowAdditions = True

        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form.AllowEdits = True
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form.AllowDeletions = True

        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!ChangedBy.Value = AcquireUser
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!ChangedAsOf.Value = Now
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!COB_ID = Form_DISTRO.COB_ID 
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!txtALLOCATION.Value = cLatest
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!txtADJ_DATE = Date
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!txtDISTRO_NUM = strDISTRO_NUM
        Form_DISTRO.sfALLO.Form!txtADJUSTMENT.SetFocus



    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please always give the full error message, not just the number. -- System functions like `Now()` not working is often caused by broken references.

Comment: @Andre, I added the full description. This morning, I uninstalled Office 365, reinstalled it again and also did a Windows update.  The only thing I thought it could be was the fact that I use Windows 10 on Parallels on a MAC.  So -- I ran my database on another PC here at home and it is also returning the same error.

Comment: I’m also using a government laptop and I don’t receive the error. I can edit the unrelated code at home and it continues to function correctly at work.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this.  I have to bring my work laptop home and use VPN, which is very slow.  Could I somehow have implied an edit to a recordset via the form and only this version of Office 365 is catching it?